ASP.NET Core Web API conventions not inherited when extra ProducesResponseType attribute is present on a action
Refer to the following Web API conventions and the corresponding controller:
public static class MyAppConventions
{
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(ProblemDetails), StatusCodes.Status404NotFound,
                          MediaTypeNames.Application.ProblemJson)]
    [ApiConventionNameMatch(ApiConventionNameMatchBehavior.Prefix)]
    public static void Get()
    { }
}

[ApiConventionType(typeof(MyAppConvention))]
[Route("test")]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetData()
    {
        if (condition)
            return NotFound();
        else
            return Ok(new TestDto());
    }
}

Problem
If I add an extra ProducesResponseType to mark a custom response code not present in the relevant convention, then it ignores the convention attributes.
[ApiConventionType(typeof(MyAppConvention))]
[Route("test")]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(TestDto), StatusCodes.Status200Ok, MediaTypeNames.Application.Json)]
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetData()
    {
        if (condition)
            return NotFound();
        else
            return Ok(new TestDto());
    }
}

Are there any workarounds for this? This messes with the OpenAPI analyzers added to the project.
References

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/conventions?view=aspnetcore-8.0
Custom Web API Conventions are not working with ODataController


Based on your description, you want to keep the MyAppConventions unchanged, while add attributes on action level to combine both your Convention and attribute on your specific action. It is not feasible as it is expected that the deeper level overrides the outer level. So as a workaround you could add both your conventions and the the attribute on your action.

We ran into the same issue and decided to write our own EndpointConventionBuilder middleware to change the default behavior.
The middlewar will check your controller actions if they contain ProducesResponseTypeAttribute and also ApiConventionResult properties. If thats the case it will copy the ProducesResponseTypeAttribute from the convention to the metadata of your endpoint. In cases where you really want to override the response types defined in your API convention you can add the IgnoreConventionResponseTypesAttribute
/// <summary>
/// Extension methods for <see cref="IEndpointConventionBuilder"/>.
/// </summary>
public static class IEndpointConventionBuilderExtensions
{

    /// <summary>
    /// By default reponse types defined by <see cref="ApiConventionTypeAttribute"/> are overwritten by <see cref="ProducesResponseTypeAttribute"/> on the action.
    /// To always apply response types from the convention, this method can be used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// To disable this behavior on a specific action, apply <see cref="IgnoreConventionResponseTypesAttribute"/> attribute on the action.
    /// </remarks>
    /// <param name="builder">The builder.</param>
    public static void AddApiConventionResponseTypes(this IEndpointConventionBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Add(builder =>
        {
            var action = builder.Metadata.OfType<ControllerActionDescriptor>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (action is not null)
            {
                if (builder.Metadata.OfType<IgnoreConventionResponseTypesAttribute>().Any()) return;
                var explicitResponseTypes = builder.Metadata.OfType<ProducesResponseTypeAttribute>().ToList();
                if (explicitResponseTypes.Count > 0)
                {
                    if (action.Properties.TryGetValue(typeof(ApiConventionResult), out var result) && result is ApiConventionResult apiConventionResult)
                    {
                        foreach (var response in apiConventionResult.ResponseMetadataProviders)
                        {
                            action.EndpointMetadata.Add(response);
                            action.FilterDescriptors.Add(new FilterDescriptor(response, 30));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

This also allows you to add the following attributes on controller action where you want to override the response types defined in your API conventions
/// <summary>
/// An attribute that specifies that the controller method that this attribute is applied to 
/// should ignore additional response types defined by <see cref="ApiConventionTypeAttribute"/>.
/// </summary>
/// <seealso cref="System.Attribute" />
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class IgnoreConventionResponseTypesAttribute : Attribute
{
}

You have to attach the middleware to your MapControllers() call in startup
app.MapControllers().AddApiConventionResponseTypes();

